# Other functions to use than trim

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm having trouble passing a variable from PHP to Javascript. It works as follows

You enter how much of a particular stock you want ie - 10 apples and it validates it against three different methods:

1. If its a number
2. If its not empty
3. If there is enough stock available

**Javascript**

```
   function numCheck() 
    {
        var stockavailable =document.getElementById('stock_value').value;
        var enteredChar = document.getElementById('add_value').value;

        if (isNaN(enteredChar))
        {
            alert("Not a Number!");
            return false;
        }

        if (enteredChar=="")
        {
            alert("Empty!");
            return false;
        }

        if (enteredChar > stockavailable)
        {   
            alert("not enough stock");
            return false;
        }   

    }
```

**PHP**

```
echo '<form name="form1">';
echo '<table class="Grocery-table">'; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    $stock =$row['in_stock'];
    $product_id = $row['product_id'];

   echo "<tr><td><b>Product ID</b></td>"; 
   echo "<td>";     
   echo $product_id;
   echo "</td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><td><b>Product Name</b></td>";
   echo "<td>";
   echo $row['product_name'];
   echo "</td></tr>"; 
   echo "<tr><td><b>Unit Price</b></td>";
   echo "<td>";
   echo $stock;
   echo "</td></tr>"; 
   echo "<tr><td><b>Unit Quantity</b></td>";
   echo "<td>";
   echo $row['unit_quantity'];
   echo "</td></tr>"; 
   echo "<tr><td><b>In Stock</b></td>";
   echo "<td>";
   echo $row['in_stock'];
   echo "</td></tr>";
   echo '<tr><td><b>Add</b></td><td><Input type="text" id="add_value" name="cart"></input><Input type="hidden" id="stock_value" name="stock_value" value ="'.trim($stock).'"></input></td></tr>';
 echo '<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return numCheck()"></td></tr>';

    }
  echo "</table>"; 
  echo "</form>";
```

For some reason the **trim** function wont allow me to enter values of different dominations. For example if the stock is 1200 - i can only enter values that begin with 1  not 2,3,4,5 etc.

Comment: if you look at the Input type = Hidden ... value ="'.trim($stock).'"

Comment: where it not allows to enter 2,3,4,5,etc?

Comment: as per the comment below i believe "1" > "2" etc .. therefore its not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"2" > "10"`, but `2 < 10`. See the problem here?

You will need to cast your values from the input fields to numbers because the default `.value` will return a string:

```
var stockavailable = parseInt(document.getElementById('stock_value').value, 10);
var enteredChar = parseInt(document.getElementById('add_value').value, 10);
```

You can use `parseInt(num, 10)` for integers or `parseFloat(num)` for floats, both will return a double floating point, but parseInt will round down to nearest whole number.

Comment: is there any way i can set it to be a dynamic value instead of 10? ie the amount of product available in the database?

Comment: @JavaHater `parseInt(num, 10)` is telling that you want to parse `num` in base 10. eg: `parseInt('20', 10) === 20`. If you for instance want to parse a binary number you can use base 2: `parseInt('110', 2) === 6`